# tkinter how do i calculate the normal vector and the conservation of the kinetic energy of all particles in python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, formula, calculation, particles

I was trying to calculate the normal vector n [formula for normal vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0hC4.png) and the tangential vectors t [tangential vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/514ir.png) [n=v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX1ju.png) of two particles p1 and p2 to find the conservation of kinetic energy [conservation of energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAFLS.png)
or here's another way to write the formula: [formula 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfUku.png)
but i don't really know where and how in the code to implent this?

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from math import *
myHeight=250#400
myWidth=400#800
mySpeed=20#100

col= randint(0,255)
radius = randint(0,50)
print (col)
#x= 60 


global particules
particules = []

def initialiseParticule(dx,dy,radius,color):
    x, y = randint(0,myWidth),  randint(0,myHeight) #100
    radius = randint(0,10)
    #color = randint(0,255)
    #col1=str(color)
    k = myCanvas.create_oval(x-radius,y-radius,\
                         x+radius,y+radius,\
                         width=2,fill=color)
    b = [x, y, dx, dy, radius]
    particules.append(b)

    #print(k)


  
def updateParticules():

  N = len(particules)
  for i in range(N):  
      
      # update displacement 
      particules[i][0] += particules[i][2]
      particules[i][1] += particules[i][3]

      #xi += vxi
      #yi += vyi
      
      # collision with walls 
      if particules[i][0]<particules[i][4]or particules[i][0]>=myWidth-particules[i][4]:    
            particules[i][2] *= -1
      if particules[i][1]<particules[i][4] or particules[i][1]>=myHeight-particules[i][4]:
            particules[i][3] *= -1

      # collision with other particles 
      for j in range(N):
        if i != j:

          xi, yi = particules[i][0], particules[i][1]
          vxi, vyi = particules[i][2], particules[i][3]

          xj, yj = particules[j][0], particules[j][1]
          vxj, vyj = particules[j][2], particules[j][3]

          dij = sqrt((xi-xj)**2 + (yi-yj)**2)
          # print(dij)
          #  # collision !!!
          if dij <= particules[i][4]+particules[j][4]:
            particules[i][2] *= -1
            particules[j][2] *= -1
            particules[i][3] *= -1
            particules[j][3] *= -1


      r = particules[i][4]
      myCanvas.coords(i+1, particules[i][0]-r, particules[i][1]-r,
                        particules[i][0]+r, particules[i][1]+r)

 
    
def animation():
    miseAJourBalles()
    myCanvas.after(mySpeed, animation)


mainWindow=Tk()
mainWindow.title('Pong')
#mainWindow.geometry(str(myWidth)+'x'+str(myHeight+100))
myCanvas=Canvas(mainWindow, bg='dark grey', height=myHeight, width=myWidth)
myCanvas.pack(side=TOP)

N = 3
for n in range(N):
#  initialiseParticules( -1, -1, radius,'randint(0,10)') 
 initialiseParticules( -1, -1, radius,'pink') 



animation()

#bou=Button(mainWindow,text="Leave",command=mainWindow.destroy) 
#bou.pack() 

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think that you wanted to use `(particules[i][4] + particules[j][4])**2` instead of `particules[i][4] + particules[j][4]`.

Comment: I think this belongs on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Calculating vectors has nothing to do with tkinter. You should tag this so that people interested in math and/or physics will see it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did this already ...

Comment: @Programmer and Brayn Oakley ok thanks ill ask math then

Comment: @nightslqyer Do you mind deleting this question?